# Monodroid - How to pass strings between activities

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I try to pass a decimal between two activities. And I did like this:

First Activity:

```
var Valori = new Intent (this , typeof (ResoultTabel));
string xa = a.Text;
Valori.PutExtra ( xa , xa );
StartActivity (Valori);
```

The other Activity (ResoultTabel);

```
string text = Intent.GetStringExtra (xa);
double a = Convert.ToDouble (text);
```

And I get error : The name 'xa' does not exist in the current context.

After this I declare the 'xa' in the second activity too.

```
string xa;
```

And I get this error: Use of unassigned local variable 'xa'.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First parameter is key and second parametr is value of key in  it.

do like this:

```
Valori.PutExtra ( "xa" , xa );
```

and in next activity:

```
string text = Intent.GetStringExtra ("xa");
```

Comment: I was close.Thank you! :)